# Angular: check if form element is required (whether or not it's already filled in)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm aware that you can use `$scope.formName.fieldName.$error.required` to find out if a specific field has a required attribute which has not been fulfilled. You can also use `$scope.formName.$error.required` to find all fields in a form that have an unsatisfied required attribute.

I'm looking to find out weather or not a field is required. This is regardless of weather or not the user has already filled in that field. How can I do this?

N.B. as a result I want something like this `{{countFilledRequiredFields()}}/{{countAllRequiredFields()}}`, then I can tell the user something like: **you have filled in 3/5 of the required fields**

Answer (score 1):

You can get all fields that have *satisfied* the required attribute from:

```
$scope.formName.$$success.required
```

And since you can get all fields that have an unsatisfied required attribute from:

```
$scope.formName.$error.required
```

You can easily combine the two to achieve what you want. i.e.

```
allRequiredFieldsCount =
    $scope.formName.$$success.required.length +
    $scope.formName.$error.required.length;

filledRequiredFieldsCount = $scope.formName.$$success.required.length;
```

Comment: Thanks @saeb. ` $scope.formName.$$success.required` seems to give me even fields which have `ng-required="false"`. So it's not really giving me what I want.
To see which fields are being used I use `$scope.formName.$$success.required.map(function(elem){return elem.$name})` this will give an array of the names. From here I can see that even the fields with `ng-required="false"` are considered to have fulfilled the `required` attribute.

Comment: @Kholofelo, I tested your map list and noted that the not required fields go first, and the required ones go last. Perhaps that could be helpful.